# How to evaluate the integral $ \int_{0}^{2\pi}|2e^{it}-1|^2 2ie^{it} dt $?

Tags: integration

How to evaluate the integral $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|2e^{it}-1|^2 2ie^{it} dt $$

I have attempted it replacing $e^{it}$ with $\cos t +i\sin t$ but it doesn't seem to be working. How would I go about this?

Comment: Use $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$ and $|z|^2=z\bar z$.

Comment: I have used that. I am getting 0 but the answer is -8pi i

Answer (score 3):

> *Motto:* Complex exponentials are often simpler to manipulate than their underlying cosine and sine parts.

Several answers are already posted, which rush to cosine-sine decompositions at the expense of overly long computations, so let us explain in details how to apply the general principle above to the present case.

**1.** We start with the identities $$|z|^2=z\cdot\bar z\qquad \overline{e^{it}}=e^{-it}$$ They yield at once $$|2e^{it}-1|^2e^{it}=(2e^{it}-1)(2e^{-it}-1)e^{it}=5e^{it}\color{red}{-2}-2e^{2it}\tag{$\ast$}$$
The good news is that, basically, the computation part is already over... To see why, let us continue.

**2.** Our second ingredient is that, for every nonzero integer $n$, $$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{int}dt=0$$ which can be proven in several different, elementary, ways, and that the integral for $n=0$ is simply $2\pi$. Thus, once integrated over $(0,2\pi)$, the only remaining term in the expansion $(\ast)$ is $\color{red}{-2}$.

**3.** Finally, using 1. and 2., $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|2e^{it}-1|^2 2ie^{it} dt=2i\int_0^{2\pi}(\color{red}{-2})\,dt=2i\cdot(\color{red}{-2})\cdot2\pi=-8i\pi$$

Comment: And now a downvote... This page is becoming more and more amusing, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|2e^{it}-1|^2 2ie^{it}dt=\\
\int_{0}^{2\pi} |2\cos(t)+i\sin(t)-1|^2 2e^{it}dt=\\
\int_{0}^{2\pi} ((2\cos(t)-1)^2+(2\sin(t))^2) 2ie^{it}dt=\\
\int_{0}^{2\pi} (4\cos(t)^2+4\sin(t)^2+1-4\cos(t)) 2ie^{it}dt=\\
\int_{0}^{2\pi} (5-4\cos(t))2i(\cos(t)+i\sin(t)) dt=...$

Comment: You seem to have made redundant several key terms

Comment: @aprilanalysis I see that you have included the integral in the post itself, and i see that i indeed read the title wrong (it doesnt render tex). I have edited my answer, and I hope you can solve it from here. Please tell me if you need more help!

Answer (score 0):

$$ I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}|2e^{it}-1|^2 2ie^{it} dt $$

If $|2e^{it}-1| $, is a module of complex number then $$|2e^{it}-1|^2= (2cost -1)^2 + (2sint)^2=4cos^2t-4cost +1+4sin^2t$$.
We get $$I=2i(\int_{0}^{2\pi}4cos^2te^{it}dt-\int_{0}^{2\pi}4coste^{it}dt-i+i+\int_{0}^{2\pi}4sin^2te^{it}dt)$$
$$I_1=\int_{0}^{2\pi}cos^2te^{it}dt\\ I_2=\int_{0}^{2\pi}coste^{it}dt\\
I_3=\int_{0}^{2\pi}sin^2te^{it}dt$$

Then, in $I_1,I_2,I_3$, use the following:$$cos^2t=\frac{1+cos2t}{2},\ sin^2t=1-cos^2t,\ 2sintcost=sin2t,\ e^{it}=cost +isint$$
The result I'm getting is $-8i\pi$. Integrals $I_2$ and $I_3$ equal 0, and $I_2=\pi$.

Whole solution:

$$I_2=\int_0^{2\pi}cost(cost +isint)dt=\int_0^{2\pi}cos^2tdt+\int_0^{2\pi}isintcostdt=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1+cos2t}{2}dt+\int_0^{2\pi}i\frac{sin2t}{2}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{2}+
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{cos2t}{2}dt+\int_0^{2\pi}i\frac{sin2t}{2}dt=\pi +\frac{sin2t}{2}|_0^{2\pi}-\frac{icos2t}{4}|_0^{2\pi}=\pi$$

$$I_1=\int_0^{2\pi}cos^2t(cost+isint)dt=\int_0^{2\pi}cos^2tcostdt+\int_0^{2\pi}isintcos^2tdt\\
I_{11}=\int_0^{2\pi}cos^2tcostdt\\
I_{12}=\int_0^{2\pi}isintcos^2tdt\\
I_{11}=\int_0^{2\pi}(1-sin^2t)costdt=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-sin^2t)costdt+
\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}(1-sin^2t)costdt+\int_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}(1-sin^2t)costdt+\int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi}(1-sin^2t)costdt$$
Now, in $I_{11}$ we introduce a change of variables: $x=sint,\ dx=costdt$ and we get:
$$I_{11}=\int_0^1(1-x^2)dx+
\int_1^0(1-x^2)dx+\int_0^{-1}(1-x^2)dx+\int_{-1}^{0}(1-x^2)dx=0$$
$$I_{12}=\int_0^{2\pi}isintcos^2tdt=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}isintcos^2tdt+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}isintcos^2tdt+\int_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}isintcos^2tdt+\int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi}isintcos^2tdt$$
We introduce a change of variables in $I_{12}$ :
$x=cost,\ dx=-sintdt$ and we get:
$$I_{12}=-(\int_1^0ix^2dx+\int_0^{-1}ix^2dx+\int_{-1}^0ix^2dx+\int_0^1ix^2dx)=0$$

Edit: Previously I've written that you should be able to solve $I_1,I_2,I_3$ using partial integration, but that's not going to work, at least not for $I_2$.

Comment: You would have spared much sweat by *not* decomposing the integration domain. All odd powers of sine/cosine yield $0$.

Comment: And you (as several other users) would have spared even more sweat by not decomposing the exponential into its cosine and sine parts.